How to execute x86_64 binaries in Linux VM with Rosetta 2
Thanks to Apple's Virtualization framework it is possible to use Rosetta 2 inside a Linux VM to run x86_64 applications.
All the videos and resources I've found online only explain how to install x86 applications using the apt package manager by appending :amd64 to the application name.
For example:
sudo apt install libx11-6:amd64

You also need to add the amd64 apt repositories such as described in the Github repository macOS-Linux-VM-with-Rosetta.
But I'm wondering, and I haven't found an answer yet, how to execute x86_64 binaries that I have manually downloaded somewhere or compiled on my own, not through the apt registry.
I'm using Parallels 20.1.1 on an M1 Mac Pro running macOS 15.0.1, I have created a Ubuntu 22.04.2 VM with the Parallels Rosetta setting enabled.
I have also enabled Rosetta in my VM using the script provided by Parallels as described in Using Rosetta to run x86-64 Docker Containers and Binaries in Linux virtual machines with Parallels Desktop.
$ sudo ./rosetta_x86_sources.sh enable
$ sudo apt update 

But when I execute a x86 binary inside this VM I get an error indicating that I'm running the wrong platform.
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

how can I execute x86_64 binaries on a Linux VM with Rosetta 2?

Parallels Desktop Pro and Business Edition 20 have had enough time to implement all of Apple’s requirements. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/virtualization/running_intel_binaries_in_linux_vms_with_rosetta do any x86_64 binaries work like the edge example in the KB 129871 troubleshooting section?

Yes, I have tried their Ubuntu 24.04 (with Rosetta) image, and installed microsoft edge using the downloaded .deb file and the installation worked, starting the application didnt work yet though.

Just sharing that it DOES work with Parallels Pro w/ Rosetta.  I'm using their Ubuntu (shudder) image to run MS SQL Server.

@MarcWilson did you install it through apt or did you download the binary somewhere?

I used their Ubuntu + Rosetta and then followed the instructions here https://kb.parallels.com/129699 for running SQL Server.
